# Sourcing Informative Priors from an already conducted Empirical Study in brms package in R

Tags: r, regression, bayesian, mixed-model, brms

I am conducting two studies (with 15 participants) and my study is based on two already conducted studies with a very similar objective and method. One of the studies contain only the results, and one of them have data available online. This is on face and emotion perception with static faces and dynamic faces. I would like to use informed priors and conduct bayesian statistical inferencing to understand if the predictors (social anxiety) predict the outcome (sensitivity to threatening face expressions). I have multiple trials per participant (and the num of trials vary for each) so I would like to do a mixed effects modelling with informed priors based on the the two studies.

Could someone perhaps help me understand the syntax of the `set_priors()` function in `brms`? Or help me with how to source those from the previous studies?

I have been scouring statistics articles and have understood the whats and whys but not exactly how to do it. I have used uninformed priors before and I am comfortable with `brms` (but not with setting my own priors).

Comment: Hi Deepshikha. Welcome to CV. I have trimmed down your post. Could you please elaborate what created hindrances in comprehending the concerned syntax? Also as you said you already used the relevant technique, could you care to please expand on why `brms` is posing any problems?

Comment: Are you asking how to find informative priors in general, or specifically how to use `set_priors()` in brms? For the latter there's no better place to start than [the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/brms/versions/2.19.0/topics/set_prior).